# how to crawl hidden type html in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl and get data from a website. I wanna know and display the data to my website.

I am having trouble with crawling data from my university website.

I want to know body -> document -> document -> ,,,

but when I try to crawl with BeautifulSoup, I can't do this

I really need this data and I haven't used any other programming language...

how can i crawl?

below is picture and red line would be problem I think.

[image: in python]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://sg.eulji.ac.kr/ejuv')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html')

print(soup)
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<title>::-===-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-::</title>
<link href="/html/css/redmond_ori/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/html/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/html/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- netFunnel연결 js파일 -->
<!-- <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/html/js/netfunnel/netfunnel.js" charset=utf-8></SCRIPT> -->
<script charset="euc-kr" src="/html/js/netfunnel/netfunnel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
  body {
    margin : 0px;
    padding : 0px;
  }
  .ui-widget{font-size:0.9em}
</style>
<script>
function msgAlert(msg){
    $("#msg").html(msg.replace(/\r|\n/gi,"<br>"));
    $("#message").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        buttons: {
            " close ": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        position: {
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: $("body"),
            within: $("body")
            }

    }).height('auto');// end dialog
}
function msgConfirm(msg){
        $("#msg").html(msg.replace(/\r|\n/gi,"<br>"));
        $("#message").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            width: 500,
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            buttons: {
                " 확인 ": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    location.href= "/ejuv/login?attribute=logOut&fake="+new Date();             
                },
                " 닫기 ": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }

        });// end dialog
    }
function setToken(token) {
    $("#token").val(token);
}
function getToken() {
    return $("#token").val();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="message" style="display:none;" title="알림"><table align="center" style="font-size:9pt;"><tr><td valign="bottom"><div id="msg"></div></td></tr></table></div>
<input id="token" name="token" type="hidden"/>
<iframe name="Main" scrolling="auto" src="/ejuv/login?attribute=login" style="position: absolute; width:100%; height:100%; border: none"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is probably because the value inside the `hidden input` is being set dynamically using Javascript, that's probably the CSRF token. If that's the case you probably need `Selenium` to scrape the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you need to get inside the iframe in which case use the iframe `src` value direct

```
http://obscured_info/ejuv/login?attribute=login
```

You are then working with the iframe document.

This link is passed to requests (see dark red rectangle)

[image]

Comment: See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/DelectableLovelyInfinity)

Comment: @CodeIt I was worried about using the actual link given the OP went to the effort of obscuring some info. However, if they don't mind the full link I will accept proposed edit.

Comment: @QHarr I will try this way !!

Comment: @QHarr Can you tell me how the link works and the one I mentioned in the post didn't work?

Comment: The link which works is the one to the document inside the iframe which is the login document. An iframe is its own [browsing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/browsing_context). If you examine the response from your original url via requests there is no loading of the iframe document so you have only the "shell" iframe tag in the response.